# PowerShell 2.0 and how to handle exceptions?

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-2.0

Why I get error message printed on the console when running these two simple samples ? 
I want that I get "Error testing :)" printed on the console insted of:

> Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is
>   unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800706BA) At line:3 char:15
>   +     Get-WmiObject <<<<  -ComputerName possibly.nonexisting.domain.com
>   -Credential (Get-Credential) -Class Win32_logicaldisk 
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject],
>   COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

or

> Attempted to divide by zero. At line:3
>   char:13
>   +         $i = 1/ <<<< 0
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
>   ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

First example:

```
try
{
    $i = 1/0   
    Write-Host $i     
}
catch [Exception]
{ 
    Write-Host "Error testing :)" 
}
```

Second example:

```
try
{
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName possibly.nonexisting.domain.com -Credential (Get-Credential) -Class Win32_logicaldisk 
}
catch [Exception]
{ 
    Write-Host "Error testing :)" 
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First example**

The error happens at compile/parsing time (PowerShell is clever enough), so that the code is not even executed and it cannot catch anything, indeed. Try this code instead and you will catch an exception:

```
try
{
    $x = 0
    $i = 1/$x
    Write-Host $i
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error testing :)"
}
```

---

**Second example**

If you set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` globally then you will get "Error testing :)" printed, as expected. But your `$ErrorActionPreference` is presumably `'Continue'`: in that case there is no terminating error/exception and you just get the non terminating error message printed to the host by the engine.

Instead of the global `$ErrorActionPreference` option you can also play with `Get-WmiObject` parameter `ErrorAction`. Try to set it to `Stop` and you will catch an exception.

```
try
{
    Get-WmiObject -ErrorAction Stop -ComputerName possibly.nonexisting.domain.com -Credential (Get-Credential) -Class Win32_logicaldisk
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error testing :)"
}
```

Comment: So if the $ErrorActionPreference is set to 'Continue' (which is default) you just get error mesage printed out and script normaly continue ?

Comment: And if $ErrorActionPreference is set to 'Stop' then will be script execution stopped at first unhandled exception ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Personally, I find this default option confusing and slightly dangerous: it may lead to unexpected continuations too often. I would prefer ‘Stop’ by default, and that’s what I do in my PS profiles first.

Comment: You can also suppress it with the common parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and capture the error with the common parameter `-ErrorVariable someVariableName` so you can test for it: `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName possibly.nonexisting.domain.com -Credential (Get-Credential) -Class Win32_logicaldisk -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable noWMI; if($NoWMI) {  Write-Host "Error testing :)" }`