# Foreach error handling in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to catch and save bad names in a foreach loop? I have the following:

```
$CollectionName = "Import Test"
$PCName = Import-Csv "C:\Powershell\import_test.csv" 
foreach($computer in $PCName) {
Add-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule -CollectionName $CollectionName -ResourceID $(Get-   CMDevice -Name $computer.computername).ResourceID
}
```

What I would like to do is that if there is a bad name in the csv then instead of displaying the "Cannot validate argument" error I currently get, just output the failed name to a text file.

Thanks

Comment: Have you played with `-ErrorAction`?  Also, here's a page about catching exceptions in powershell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691874/powershell-2-0-and-how-to-handle-exceptions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Put the statement(s) inside the loop in a `try..catch` block:

```
foreach($computer in $PCName) {
  try {
    Add-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule ...
  } catch {
    "Bad name: $name" | Out-File 'C:\bad_names.txt' -Append
  }
}
```

If the error is a non-terminating error (i.e. displays an error message, but isn't caught by `try..catch`), you can turn it into a terminating error by adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to the command or by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfect. I've read about try catch but haven't used them before.